# NSTextView Chinese/Unicode Characters

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, nstextview

I have a piece of text drawn in my cocoa app but I also need to draw it in a NSTextField and a NSTextView and look exactly the same, they all usually draw fine but if there are unicode or Chinese characters in the text then the NSTextView has large line spaces between the lines, it works perfectly in the nstextfield and when drawing normally.

I have tried every setting that I can find but none affect this issue, has anyone run into this issue before and know of a fix?

You can see the issue in a screenshot at http://cl.ly/3e0U1T2U2G2z341j3O3T
[image: NSTextView Chinese/Unicode Characters]

Here is my test code to show the issue

```
NSTextField *textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(5, 50, 100, 100)];
[textField setStringValue:@"え？移転！？ TESTTestTer 友達の旦那の店 THIS IS A TEST THIS IS A TEST"];
[textField setBordered:NO];
[textField setBezeled:NO];
[textField setAllowsEditingTextAttributes:YES];
[textField setDelegate:self];
[textField setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"LucidaGrande" size:12.0]];
[textField setTextColor:[NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:(74.0/255.0) green:(74.0/255.0) blue:(74.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]];
[[window contentView] addSubview: textField];

NSTextView *textView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(200, 50, 100, 100)];
[textView setString:@"え？移転！？ TEST TestTer 友達の旦那の店 THIS IS A TEST THIS IS A TEST"];
[textView setDelegate:self];
[textView setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"LucidaGrande" size:12.0]];
[textView setTextColor:[NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:(74.0/255.0) green:(74.0/255.0) blue:(74.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]];
[[textView layoutManager] setTypesetterBehavior:NSTypesetterBehavior_10_2_WithCompatibility];
[[textView textContainer] setLineFragmentPadding:0.0];
[[window contentView] addSubview: textView];
```

Comment: What does the text view's `defaultParagraphStyle` look like?

Comment: Just NSMutableParagraphStyle * aParagraphStyle = [[[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init] autorelease];  [aParagraphStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping]; I have tried all of the paragraph options but none seem to make a difference

Comment: David: So you're changing the text view's paragraph style? Were you doing that before? What does the default paragraph style look like if you leave it alone?

Comment: I was not changing the default paragraph style in those screenshots but if I do change it using setDefaultParagraphStyle it doesn't make any difference, I have tried setting max line height, min line height, line spacing etc... The NSTextView matches the nstextfield perfectly if there are no Chinese, Unicode or other characters in it

Comment: Changing the layout manager typesetter behavior from 10_2 to 10_4 seems to make the gaps between lines much closer but doesn't fully fix the issue, I changed it to [[textView2 layoutManager] setTypesetterBehavior:NSTypesetterBehavior_10_4];

Comment: Then again we return to my question: What does the (default) default paragraph style look like?